# What's the meaning of "it was collapsing in on itself"

Tags: prepositions

From "The Da Vinci Code":

> (Describing a scheme) It had all begun as a holy cause. A brilliantly crafted scheme. Now, like a house of cards, it was collapsing ***in on itself***, and the end was nowhere in sight.

How to understand the part "in on itself"? I can understand if it's only "collapsing itself", but what's the meaning of "in on" here?

Comment: You can't say "Collapsing itself". You have to use the preposition *on* to introduce "itself". You have to consider "collapse in" (*in* reinforcing the compactness of the fall, no elements spilling astray) as one group, an "on itself" as another group.

Comment: I differ on this! A differently said sentence *...collapsed itself* is absolutely okay. *"... when the Workingmen's party virtually demolished the Democratic organization in San Francisco and then suddenly **collapsed itself.**"*

Comment: @MaulikV You're using the verb in a different meaning in your example. In OP's context the "on" is necessary.

Comment: @Laure Tell me this - *My brain was collapsing itself.* - is it incorrect?

Comment: @MaulikV I would never say it, if I were ever to use the verb "collapse" for my brain I'd say "my brain collapses" or "my brain collapses on itself". I just can't conceive my brain as the cause of its own collapse which its transitive use in that case would mean to me. But of course **grammatically** speaking the sentence is correct. It depends what you want to say.

Comment: @Laure exactly. That's what I mentioned in my answer. The scheme, just like cards, collapsed on itself. Let me put this clearly in my answer. I think it passed a wrong message.

Comment: @Maulik, when they said the Workingmen's party collapsed itself, they meant that "it itself collapsed". The _itself_ was just there for emphasis. It was poorly written I think, given that ambiguity.

Comment: @Dangph there are some more examples as well... *Russia was **collapsing itself** but even before the disintegration of the Soviet empire, a decision of noninterference in the former communist countries.* In short, it's not utterly wrong!

Comment: @Maulik, if something is collapsing itself, then it is actively trying to make itself collapse. I can't think of an good example of where that might happen. Maybe one of those Transformer robots from the cartoons and movies. It collapses itself into a car (or whatever). I think in "Russia was collapsing itself", the _itself_ again is just for emphasis. They should have changed the word order: "Russia was itself collapsing." (Normally however you can put the _itself_ afterwards, like for example in "I like cheese myself.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something simply *collapses*, it falls more or less straight down.  While it was standing, it occupied a certain amount of space on the ground.  When the collapse is complete, the thing is much shorter, but takes up more space on the ground, because it spread out or tilted over as it fell.

If you picture a person standing, they occupy only about a square foot of ground space; when they collapse, their knees would buckle and the start of the fall would be straight downward, but not everything bends in the same way and the person would end up lying on the ground, probably taking 5 or 6 square feet of space.

When something *collapses in on itself*, it falls more or less straight down, **and** it ends up taking no more ground space when fallen than it did while standing.  Obviously a person can't really do this, but a building can be made to do it.  (check out [wikipedia's page on Building Implosions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_implosion) for some images and videos.)

Both prepositions are necessary; you can't collapse *on yourself* because the *on*, when used alone with *collapse*, is describing where you land.  (You might "collapse on the floor", or "collapse on the bed"; but "collapse on yourself" sounds like you end up floating in mid-air since you didn't actually land on anything else.)  And you can't collapse *in yourself* because *in*, when used alone with *collapse*, describes either the general manner in which you end up, or something that you do while collapsing.  (You might "collapse in a heap", or "collapse in a flood of tears".)  When you combine both prepositions, though, *in* describes the direction of your collapse (as being not a normal "spreading-out-as-you-fall" collapse) and *on* now specifies correctly where you (or the parts of you that did not spread out as normally expected) landed.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the scheme (just like a house of cards) collapsed on itself. In other words, the external efforts played no major role in the failure of the scheme.

*in* is *[an adverbial particle](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/adverb-particles/)* which is quite optional in this case. You can remove it and it'll still convey the message.

It's a writing style basically.

[Note that not in all cases, removing *adverbial particles* will keep its meaning intact. There, they have to be there.]

Comment: Saying "it is only *collapsing on itself*" means "collapse in on" is not correct. Not only is *collapse in on* correct, but common in a scientific context.

Comment: Is this comment for me or the OP? I clarified this all in my answer.

Comment: For you, you start your answer by saying "It's collapsing on itself only!" which you in part contradict in the rest of your answer.

Comment: What do you think *in* and *on* are? What difference does it make?

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes! I'm nowhere  discussing about "in" or "on", I'm just pointing out that you cannot say that only *collapsing on itself* is correct, which is what your first sentence means. I'm not discussing about the rest of your answer.

Comment: And I was not the one to downvote your answer, in case you wondered.

Comment: @Laure I'm down-vote proof! :) So, don't worry about it. I think, *the building collapsed in on itself* is equal to *the building collapsed on itself.*

Comment: I think the OP would also like to hear about "on", since they expect "It was collapsing itself" without either preposition.

Comment: @snailplane *...without either preposition?*... there's only one preposition *on)... *in* is an adverbial particle. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your analysis is possible, but I see no reason not to call them both prepositions, myself.

Answer (score 1):

The usage (and it's pretty common) is, as you say, to "collapse in on itself."
A [web search](https://www.google.com.au/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%22collapsed+in+on+itself%22&btnG=Search&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gws_rd=ssl) (and I just performed one) produced innumerable results.

On the other hand, I don't remember hearing of anything simply "collapsing on itself," again confirmed by a lesser number of [search results](https://www.google.com.au/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%22collapsed+on+itself%22&btnG=Search&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gws_rd=ssl).

Both expressions are perfectly self-explanatory and visual in their imagery. There is also the possible implication that anything which collapses [in] on itself does so without any external pressure; as if its collapse results from poor design at the outset, or physical scientific inevitability.

Comment: Just a side note, don't get driven by the number of Google Search results. :)

Comment: [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the metaphor might have arisen through astronomical explanations of a black hole as star which collapses in on itself.(*Inwardly*, towards its centre). Pretty powerful imagery.

Aside: We Aussies, far from quoting expressions faithfully as they were originally coined, actually *prefer* to modify. Hence the description of, say, an egotistical tyrant in a workplace, whose very ideas eventually bring about his own undoing, whose plans "collapsed in on themselves" like the death of a red dwarf star, someone'll come up with an inelegant line like, "He finally disappeared up his own [expletive]"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think houses of cards generally collapse in on themselves. They more just fall down in a heap, so I don't think it's really the right expression to use here. (Dan Brown really is a bad writer.) Nonetheless, "collapse in on itself" is good English. If something is collapsing on in itself, then parts of the thing are falling or moving IN towards the center, and ON to other parts at the center.

If some of the walls of an old house fell in, and the roof fell down, you could say the house collapsed in on itself.